# Angular 7/json server: post request only accepts id

Tags: angular, post, json-server

Im working with Angular 7 and json-server; at the moment I can successfully work with get and delete method's, but the post method is only posting the id and ignoring the 3 other propertys of the same class

Home HTML

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="addUser()" class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
          <input required class="form-control top-dist" placeholder="name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="hero.name" name="name" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
          <input required type="number" class="form-control top-dist"  placeholder="age" name="age" [(ngModel)]="hero.age"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
          <input required name="email" class="form-control top-dist" type="email"  placeholder="email" [(ngModel)]="hero.email" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 text-center">
          <div >
            <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-danger top-dist " />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Home TS:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[];
  hero: Hero = {
    id: null,
    name: null,
    age: null,
    email:null
  };
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  getHeroes() {
    this.dataService.getHeroes().subscribe(data => {
      this.heroes = data;
      console.log(data)
    })
  }
  addUser(){
    if(this.hero.name!=null && this.hero.age!=null && this.hero.email!=null){
    this.dataService.addUser(this.hero).subscribe((data: Hero)=>{console.log(data)})
    }  
  };
}
```

The Service:

```
addUser(user: Hero){
  console.log(user) ---> logs all fields
  if(user.id===null){
    return this.http.post<Hero>(this.url, user,  {
      headers: new HttpHeaders ({
        'Content-Type':'aplication/json'
      })

    })
}    
}
```

In the service I can see that all user's fields are loged into the console, but back on home component, logging the subscribed observable, I can only see the ID, therefore only the id is rendered after. Can someone help?

This is the log of home. The first four were written in the file, the others with the post request:

[image]

Comment: What is the return type of the API endpoint?

Comment: Im going to edit with a snapshot

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the API endpoint is setup to only return Id on POST requests, which is a common pattern. To get around overwriting your other object properties, one thing you can try:

```
this.dataService.addUser(this.hero).subscribe(
    (data: id) => this.hero = Object.assign({}, this.hero, { id: id })
)
```

Comment: it doesnt accept data type id, so I tried `        (data: Hero) => this.hero = Object.assign({}, this.hero, { hero: Hero }))
` but it didnt work...

Comment: The type ```Hero```  doesn't have an id property? I guess the question becomes-- why do we need to re-assign anything back from the server? Why not: ```.subscribe()```?

Comment: type Hero has id and its type is number. As for the subscribe, am I not doing it?

Comment: You're doing the subscribe, my point was more, why put any logic inside the subscribe block? If we don't need to do anything with the data. But if Hero does have an id property, we should assign to it. So I'm confused when you say ```it doesnt accept data type id```.

Comment: in the subscribe method I just logged the data and it comes only with the id...im lost